# ClassCastException on SearchView using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, classcastexception, searchview

I have a searchview on my app. I can type on the searchbox, however, if I press search the app crashes. It says

`11-25 00:57:09.446: E/AndroidRuntime(1914): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView cannot be cast to android.widget.SearchView`

However, what I declared on my menu file is correct.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="Quezon City Guide"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
     android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Here is the method where I'm calling it

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, (Menu) menu);


    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
     SearchView searchView =
             (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
     searchView.setSearchableInfo(
             searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.search:

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here are my imports

```
 import android.app.SearchManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView;
 import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
```

Can someone pleas help. Thanks!

Comment: Try a clean before running your project. That always helps me

Comment: the error itself shows what was the mistake...

Comment: @Miguel, do you have implementation in `onOptionsItemSelected()` ?

Comment: Have you clean the project? And run then program?

Comment: yes. still not working.

Comment: have u implements  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener   in activity class

Comment: I have not implemented `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using trying to map the `SearchView` of the Android `actionbar` to the `SearchView` of  the `Action Bar Sherlock`. Thats your error!

Comment: What do you mean? I'm sorry still a newbie.

Comment: It's a little difficult to explain, but I'll try. Your error states your search widget package name clearly. It seems that you are trying to cast the search widget for action bar sherlock to the native search widget in android. Make sure that the search widget's are of the same type, then you will not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
private SearchView mSearchView = null;
```

into OnCreateOptionMenu use the following code

```
@Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);        
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
   setupSearchView(searchItem);
    return true;
  } 


  private void setupSearchView(MenuItem searchItem) {

            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            if (searchManager != null) {
                mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
               // mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(info);
            }    
            mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using android.widget.SearchView in menu.xml  file

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are referencing in an import statement the default Android Widget and not Sherlock Search Widget here:

```
SearchView searchView =
        (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```